# Alt-PrtSc-K not working

Tags: 14.04, shortcut-keys

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrtSc</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> is not working on my machine.  I'm currently using Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS.  The shortcut used to work on older Ubuntu releases (whose purpose was to kill the display server).  Any suggestions?

Comment: That shortcut used to kill the X server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, in Ubuntu 14.04, the Magic SysRq keys are disabled.  To enable the Magic SysRq keys open the file /etc/sysctl.d/10-magic-sysrq.conf and change the line

```
kernel.sysrq = 176
```

to

```
kernel.sysrq = 1
```

Then reboot your Linux box.

Answer (score 3):

run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` and when you see this window just select "yes".

[image]

And the next time use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>  to kill X.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but according to the Magic SysRq keys the Alt+PrntSc+K should "kill all processes on the current virtual console".  I'm wondering why this is not the case.

Comment: @KasiyA As far as I've read myself through lots of documentation, Ctrl-Alt-Backspace is NOT the same as Alt+PrtSc+K! While the former is only intended to shut down the _X server_, the latter will operate on a level much closer to the kernel, i. e. even cause some problematic drivers to get reconfigured. Hitting the SysRq key combination too often (in despair, because things went really wonky on here) even caused a __kernel panic__ here and there, whilst this has never happened with Ctrl-Alt-Backspace to this day.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what ramon wrote, here's a solution to (re-)enable <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrtSc</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> even **without reboot**!

I found it all by myself, as the documentation about it is abysmal (to say the 
least).

Here on Lubuntu, the original value in `/proc/sys/kernel/sysrq` is **176**. This caused <kbd>SysRq+K</kbd> to be completely disabled.

To understand this, you have to know a little about bits, bit masks and hexadecimal numbers:

- 176 is `$B0` in hex, or `1011 0000` in binary.

To make <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrtSc</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> work, the **second bit** must be set:

- `1011 0000  OR  0000 0100` = `1011 0100`

This will be `$B4` in hex or 180 in decimal.
So here we go:

```
$ sudo sh -c "echo 180 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq"
```

The SysRq combination should work perfectly now, and without requiring reboot nor logout.

Comment: When you say "second bit", shouldn't it be 1011 0000  OR  0000 0010 = 1011 0010?